# in Qt weatherinfo demo, some contents go out of window boundary

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

We are running the Qt weatherinfo demo for a test. It is a well known demo and here are the codes.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-embedded-weatherinfo.html
and the main source is here.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-embedded-weatherinfo-weatherinfo-cpp.html

When the code is run, it looks good and like this.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/129456552@N07/16544262919/
[image: without menu. it's ok.]
We wanted to be able to select cities. So, even though we don't use SYMBIAN, we added cities menu by commenting out the SYMBIAN code guard in the constructor as below.

```
// #if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
             menuBar()->addAction(action);
// #endif
```

Now the problem is that some contents go out of bounds of the main window.
It looks like this below(top and bottom goes out of bound).
[image: after adding menu. scene's top and bottom hidden]
I don't know much about Qt, how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you solved this? I've deleted the answer because I am unable to run the example and I couldn't repeat the problem. Nonetheless, I hope the previous post can at least offer your some directions.

Comment: @Tay2510, I tried this and that, using your answers, but the problem was that some portion of the scene-either from the top or bottom- seems to be outside of the view. While examining it, my colleague and I tried using portrait view (by resizing the main window,) and found all the contents are enclosed in the view. So with not much time to work on it, we just selected portrait view. I'll add the final code for anyone's information. But I hope to see the real answer (with landscape).

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone's information, I put down the fixes that we used to get around the problem.
After changing this or that, my smart colleague suggested trying changing it to portrait layout by changing the main windows size (so that height > width). The scene's contents happen to be all included in the view!
But if somebody has the real correct answer (using landscape), please reply to my question. Thanks.

```
   void layoutItems() {
      m_scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, width() - 1, height() - 1 + menuBar()->height());
      m_view->centerOn(width() / 2, (height()-menuBar()->height()) / 2);
   ...
   }

   void layoutItemsPortrait() {
   ...
           m_conditionItem->setPos(width() - cw - 20, height() / 2 - ch - 20 + 30);
   ...
   }
   int weatherinfo_main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   ...
       w.resize(380, 400); //520, 288);
   ...
   }
```

[image]